# Can we join two tables without any common key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join table with another table .Please check the query below. I want to join OASC T3 table .So that if i update data from this table ,Rest should be updated as well. Please help

```
SELECT distinct concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-' ,[Segment_2]) As 'AcctCode',
                T1.[AcctName], T2.[Name], T3.[Code], T3.[Name],
                T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET', T0.[DebRLTotal] AS 'UTILISED BUDGET' ,
                (T0.[DebLTotal]-T0.[DebRLTotal]) AS 'BALANCE BUDGET' 
FROM OBGT T0
    INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
    INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId],
    OASC T3
WHERE T2.[Name] = [%0]
```

As you can see in this query i am fetching data from OACT using concat function having segments. and Name from OBGT table.OACT and OBGT have inner join.so i can easily updated all data. but now the segments from OACT Segment_1 and Segment_2 is available in OASC also. but the difference is , in this table i have only segmentId field. which have two ids only, 1 and 2 . under 1 segmentId values are same as Segment_1 and under SegmentId 2 values are same with Segment_2. so i want to join OASC table. so that if i put condition from OASC table then rest data should also be updated

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much easier to understand.  You should also tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server).

Comment: Just adding T3 makes a cross join, i.e. lots of rows returned and probably not what you want. Which t3 code and name do you want for a row?

Comment: @jarlh I want it for  OACT T1 and OBGT T0

Comment: If you were to going into table `OASC` and find the record you want to display here, how would you do that? It sounds like you would first go to table `OACT` and find something, and then use that something to lookup the value in `OASC` that you need. Can you explain, in words, how you would do that by hand if all of this data were in Excel or a Txt document.

Comment: You could use `FULL OUTER JOIN OASC T3 ON 1 = 1` in order to match EVERY ROW in T3 with EVERY ROW in the results, so far.  This won't be a problem if T3 contains a single row (for example if it were some kind of configuration table.)  But if it contains a lot of rows, be ready for your result set to get huge.  Additionally, if you want to, "update data from this table ,Rest should be updated as well" consider using a [Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: @DeadZone I am not getting what you are trying to explain..can you please paste query here by adding your logic.

Comment: @DeadZone please check another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To respond to your comment, if you have the following two tables...

```
Table_A (Col1 int, Col2 char)
1,A
2,B
3,C

Table_B (Col1 int, Col2 char)
10,X
11,Y
12,Z
```

... And the following query ...

```
SELECT A.Col1, A.Col2, B.Col1, C.Col2
FROM Table_A as A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B as B ON 1 = 1
```

... You will get...

```
Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2
   1    A   10    X
   1    A   11    Y
   1    A   12    Z
   2    B   10    X
   2    B   11    Y
   2    B   12    Z
   3    C   10    X
   3    C   11    Y
   3    C   12    Z
```

I hope that clear up the full outer join part of your question.  The "update" part of your question should be handled by a trigger.

**EDIT:**
Oh!  I think I understand, now...  Your OASC table is not normalized.  In its `ID` column it will have a 1 or a 2.  When it has a 1, some other column should join to your [segment_1] column and when it has a 2 it should join with the [segment_2] column.  If I understand correctly, here is the solution...

1. You should consider properly normalizing the database.  It prevents these kind of problems in the future.  But assuming that you cannot do that...
2. You want to inner join like this: `INNER JOIN OASC ON (OASC.ID = 1 AND OASC.SomeColumn = [segment_1]) OR (OASC.ID = 2 AND OASC.SomeColumn = [segment_2])`

Comment: sorry for bit pain.. But can you please show me by editing the query. I am not getting it. i tried with outer join but no difference i am getting by using it. can you please edit query . so that i could get what exactly you want to say..

Comment: I am getting the result from oasc table but its not what i want.. as i mentioned above in OASC table two segment Id 1 and 2.. which have the same value in OACT's Segment_1 and Segment_2 . with this query i can get values for id one and   can update all data according to the segment Id 1. but i dont know which condition should i use for Segment?Id= 2.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what's not correct.  But if I understood correctly, you could replace the `ON 1 = 1` to something like `ON segment_1 = segment_2` or `ON A.segment_1 = B.segment_1 AND A.segment_2 = B.segment_2`.  By making that kind of change you will cease to join on everything and only join on key column values.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I think I finally understand what your issue is.  See my edit, above for a revised solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now, By using this query I can get the result as I want

```
SELECT distinct concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2])  As 'AcctCode',T1.[AcctName], T2.[Name],concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]),T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET KSH',
T0.[DebRLTotal] AS 'UTILISED BUDGET' , T3.[Name] , T3.[Code], 
(T0.[DebLTotal]-T0.[DebRLTotal]) AS 'BALANCE BUDGET' ,
(SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name])  where T3.SegmentId = '1') AS 'Project',
(SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name])  where T3.SegmentId = '2') AS 'Distt' 
FROM OBGT T0 INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode] INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] INNER JOIN OASC T3 ON (T3.SegmentId = '1' AND T3.Code = [Segment_1] ) OR (T3.SegmentId = '2' AND T3.Code = [Segment_2])
```

Comment: At this point, it sounds to me like your original question has been answered and this really should be a new question.  (If so, please mark your answer and post a new question identifying the problem, what you've tried so far and your expected results.)